# array within an array ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, loops

```
Input: <ArrayOfSMSIncomingMessage xmlns=\"http://sms2.cdyne.com\" xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"><SMSIncomingMessage><FromPhoneNumber>19176230250</FromPhoneNumber><IncomingMessageID>cf8ef62d-9169-4908-a527-891fca056475</IncomingMessageID><MatchedMessageID>6838594b-288f-4e9a-863c-3ad9f4d501ca</MatchedMessageID><Message>This is a test</Message><ResponseReceiveDate>2013-04-07T17:19:06.953</ResponseReceiveDate><ToPhoneNumber>13146667368</ToPhoneNumber></SMSIncomingMessage><SMSIncomingMessage><FromPhoneNumber>19176230250</FromPhoneNumber><IncomingMessageID>ebf11b38-c176-439a-a2d0-7a2bb35390df</IncomingMessageID><MatchedMessageID>6838594b-288f-4e9a-863c-3ad9f4d501ca</MatchedMessageID><Message>Does it wotk</Message><ResponseReceiveDate>2013-04-07T17:19:17.303</ResponseReceiveDate><ToPhoneNumber>13146667368</ToPhoneNumber></SMSIncomingMessage></ArrayOfSMSIncomingMessage>
Expected Output:  [["191760250", "This is a test", "2013-04-07T17:19:06.953", "13146636 8"],["191760250", "Does it wotk", "2013-04-07T17:19:17.303", "131466368"]]
```

I am a newbie but i can't solve this problem or find an answer.  The objective is to parse a text.  The problem is that I put the information into an array b and then I put array b into array c.  However, what happens is that c[0] becomes equal to c[1] even thought they should have different information.  I don't know how to fix this.

```
data='"<ArrayOfSMSIncomingMessage xmlns=\"http://sms2.cdyne.com\" xmlns:i=\" <FromPhoneNumber>191760250</FromPhoneNumber>'
data=data+'<Message>This is a test</Message><ResponseReceiveDate>2013-04-07T17:19:06.953</ResponseReceiveDate>'
data=data+'<ToPhoneNumber>13146636 8</ToPhoneNumber></SMSIncomingMessage><SMSIncomingMessage><FromPhoneNumber>191760250'
data=data+'</FromPhoneNumber><Message>Does it wotk</Message><ResponseReceiveDate>2013-04-07T17:19:17.303</ResponseRecei'
data=data+'veDate><ToPhoneNumber>131466368</ToPhoneNumber></SMSIncomingMessage></ArrayOfSMSIncomingMessage>'
a=[['<FromPhoneNumber>','</FromPhoneNumber>'],['<Message>','</Message>'],
['<ResponseReceiveDate>','</ResponseReceiveDate>'],['<ToPhoneNumber>','</ToPhoneNumber>']]
b=[]
c=[]
d=true
ii=-1
while data.index(a[0][0])!=nil do
  ii+=1
  for i in 0..3
    print "\ni is #{i} first term: #{a[i][0]} second term #{a[i][1]}\n"
    b[i]= data[data.index(a[i][0])+a[i][0].length..data.index(a[i][1])-1]
    print "b[i] is #{b[i]}\n"
  end
  print "b is #{b}\n"
  print "c is #{c}\n"
  c.push(b)
  print "c is #{c}\n"
  d=data.slice!(0,data.index('</SMSIncomingMessage>')+5)
  print "d is #{d}\n"
  print "data is #{data}\n"
end
```

Comment: in simple could you say what's your goal? give a simple input and expected output.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to parse XML. If so, you really need to do it using Nokogiri, or REXML, or *SOME* sort of XML parser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really don't understand what your code is trying to accomplish, but regarding what you say isn't working as you expect, (*However, what happens is that c[0] becomes equal to c[1] even thought they should have different information.*), the issue is that you are pushing `b` (which is a reference) onto `c`, so when you change `b`, you get the appearance of the contents of `c` changing.

Change

```
c.push(b)
```

to

```
c.push(b.dup)
```

if you want what you push onto `c` to stay the same even after you change `b`.

Comment: @user2258745 Using `b.dup` as suggested, I believe you now get the expected output (as `c`).  If so, go ahead and accept this answer.  If not, please clarify what isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

You are parsing XML. Don't waste time trying to manipulate strings, because all you'll do is generate fragile code.

Instead, use a real XML parser, which lets you navigate through the structure, and pick what you want.

First, your XML is malformed, but I worked around that by supplying a closing tag, turning it into damaged XML, but not fatally so.

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml = '<ArrayOfSMSIncomingMessage xmlns="http://sms2.cdyne.com" xmlns:i="">
  <SMSIncomingMessage>
    <FromPhoneNumber>191760250</FromPhoneNumber>
    <Message>This is a test</Message>
    <ResponseReceiveDate>2013-04-07T17:19:06.953</ResponseReceiveDate>
    <ToPhoneNumber>131466368</ToPhoneNumber>
  </SMSIncomingMessage>
  <SMSIncomingMessage>
    <FromPhoneNumber>191760250</FromPhoneNumber>
    <Message>Does it wotk</Message>
    <ResponseReceiveDate>2013-04-07T17:19:17.303</ResponseReceiveDate>
    <ToPhoneNumber>131466368</ToPhoneNumber>
  </SMSIncomingMessage>
</ArrayOfSMSIncomingMessage>'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)

pp doc.search('SMSIncomingMessage').map{ |incoming_msg|
  %w[FromPhoneNumber Message ResponseReceiveDate ToPhoneNumber].map{ |n| incoming_msg.at(n).text }
}
```

Which outputs:

```
[["191760250", "This is a test", "2013-04-07T17:19:06.953", "131466368"],
["191760250", "Does it wotk", "2013-04-07T17:19:17.303", "131466368"]]
```